# Add or Create Custom Structure Tags to Permalink

Tags: customization, permalinks

I need a permalink that is the same with function like bitly. Ex:

```
mydomain.here/rAnD0mUrL
```

I use plugin called 'WP Hash IDs' (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hashed-ids) before that turn post ID into Hash and create random character but the plugin is long abandoned and not working anymore in current version of wordpress.

I'm thinking of creating custom permalink tag like the %post_id%. is that possible? for example I want to create %short_url% that convert my post url to random short character.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a random example from one of my slides. Note: tag supposes to be in your type permastruct. `random` itself will need to be added to public query vars, but let this be a homework, and analyzed somehow.

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%random%', '(.+)', 'random=' );

add_filter( 'available_permalink_structure_tags', function ( array $tags ) : array {
    $tags['random'] = 'some random thing';
    return $tags;
});

// or 'post_link' , or any other link filter 
// note, you can have more arguments passed to callback, 
// but this depends on link.
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( string $permalink ) : string {
    if (false === strpos( $permalink, '%random%' ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }
    return str_replace( '%random%', rand(1000, 4000), $permalink);
});
```