# How to Set Both Category and Sub-Category Level at Root. It should also obey post rule as /category/sample-post and /sub-catgeory/sample-post?

Tags: permalinks

I am using WordPress website. Currently Permalink is set up at home/sample-post/ and category is set to "." In present set up my URLs for categories , sub-categories and posts are as follow.

EG Category: Insurance

Sub- Category : Health Insurance , car Insurance

**URL Set in Present Permalink Structure:**

1. Category URl: Home/Insurance
2. Sub-Category : Home/Insurance/health-insurance
3. Post URL: Home/sample-post/

**I want Different URL Structure as follow**

1. Category URL: Home/insurance
2. Category Post : Home/insurance/sample-post-A

---

3. Sub-category URL: Home/health-insurance
4. Sub-category post : Home/health-insurance/sample-post-B

**and so on for other sub categories.**

When I set up, /%category%/%postname%/

1st set of desired url is achieved but not holds true for sub-category. Any help would be appreciated. I am new at Wordpress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add or Create Custom Structure Tags to Permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301167/add-or-create-custom-structure-tags-to-permalink)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define your own rewrite tag, and add the tag into the permalink structure.

- `add_rewrite_tag()` to register the new structure tag
- `available_permalink_structure_tags` filter to add to Permalinks interface
- `post_link` filter to change the URL of posts

Below is untested and incomplete code, but should get you pretty far.

```php
add_action( 'init', static function () {
    add_rewite_tag( '%one_category%', '(.+)', 'one_category=' );
} );

add_filter( 'available_permalink_structure_tags', function ( array $tags ) : array {
    $tags['one_category'] = 'Only one category';
    return $tags;
} );

add_filter( 'post_link', static function ( string $permalink, $post ) : string {
    if ( false === stripos( $permalink, '%one_category%' ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    $category = array_pop( $categories );

    return str_replace( '%one_category%', $category->slug, $permalink );
}, 10, 2 );
```